# How to access current dashboard timestamp in Grafana transformation

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm exporting some metrics from Cloudwatch via a Metrics query that are timestamps (exported in UNIX epoch). I'd like to show a delay from now in a panel in Grafana. So I was thinking about using a transformation, and subtract the exported timestamp from `now`.

But I'm unable to find a way to access `now` timestamp. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What is the data source in your case?

Comment: @markalex Added more details. They are Clouwatch metrics extracted using a Metrics query

Comment: I don't think it's possible nor desirable to solve on Grafana's side: generally such a task should be solved on dbms' side. I'm not proficient in cloudwatch though, so I can't provide you with exact solution. Maybe look into [Metric Insights](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/query-editor/#create-a-metric-insights-query)